# Is there a python function to extract strings that contains a word?

Tags: python, string

Is there a quick and easy function to extract specific strings that contain certain words?
e.g: From this variable I want to extract all the strings containing the word "string".

```
my_strings = ["first_string",
              "second_string",
              "third_string",
              "I'm_batman",
              "fifth_string"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple check:

```py
"string" in some_string
```

which evaluates to `True` if `some_string` contains `"string"`, otherwise `False`.

E.g., if you want to have a list of all the strings in `my_strings` that contain `'string'`, you can do that by writing:

```py
[s for s in my_strings if "string" in s]
```

Comment: As you said, this returns True/False. Is there anything that returns the actual values?

Comment: @JoakimMartinTorsvik: the whole thing doesn't return True/False, that's just the `if` evaluation part. This does what you requested.

Comment: @mechanical_meat Yes, sorry, should have said 'evaluated' instead of 'returns'. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @JoakimMartinTorsvik The second snippet I wrote above is a list of the actual values

Answer (score 0):

```
my_strings = ["first_string","second_string","third_string","I'm_batman","fifth_string"]
substring = "string"
for i in range(len(my_strings)):
    if substring in my_strings[i]:
        print("Found!")
    else:
        print("Not found!")
```

Obviously replace "Found!" and "Not found!" with what you want to do to those strings that either contain or don't contain the substring.